Garden: create ball joint from C++ plugin
I'm a little but confused but can't find out how to create a ball joint from a C++ gz::sim::System plugin (from Configure function).
I found a way how to create fixed joint with: _ecm.CreateComponent(entity, gz::sim::components::DetachableJoint({linkA, linkB, "fixed"})))
In sdf/Joint.hh there is a sdf::Joint class but I have not idea how to append it. I guess it's not what I'm looking for.
I also tried(suggested by ChatGPT):
        auto jointEntity = _ecm.CreateEntity();
        _ecm.CreateComponent(jointEntity, gz::gazebo::components::Joint());
        _ecm.CreateComponent(jointEntity, gz::gazebo::components::JointType(sdf::JointType::BALL));
        _ecm.CreateComponent(jointEntity, gz::gazebo::components::Name("ball_joint"));
        _ecm.CreateComponent(jointEntity, gz::gazebo::components::ParentEntity(_entity));
        _ecm.CreateComponent(jointEntity, gz::gazebo::components::ChildLinkName("link2"));
        _ecm.CreateComponent(jointEntity, gz::gazebo::components::ParentLinkName("link1"));
        _ecm.CreateComponent(jointEntity, gz::gazebo::components::Pose(gz::math::Pose3d::Zero));

but it doesn't work (and no runtime errors)
Seems other approach is:
    sdf::Joint jojo;
    jojo.SetName("JoJo0");
    jojo.SetParentName("link2");
    jojo.SetChildName("link5");
    jojo.SetType(sdf::JointType::BALL);

    auto entityCreator = gz::sim::SdfEntityCreator(_ecm, _eventMgr);
    auto entity = entityCreator.CreateEntities(&jojo, true);
    entityCreator.SetParent(entity, _entity);

but in case of attempt to create closed loop it fails inside SDFFeatures.cc
